# How to send a message to every channel id stored in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to send a message to every channel/channelID from every guild that is in my database **Heres what i tried** and Thanks!

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, Client,} = require("discord.js");
const db = require("../../Structures/models/guild");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("post")
    .setDescription("Post Something")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages),

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const channelids = mongoose.get(`channelID_${interaction.guild.id}`);

    channelids.forEach(async (id) => {
      try {
        const channel = await client.channels.fetch(id);
        channel.send('Something');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

    await interaction.reply({content: 'Brwww'})
  },
};
```

Error

> C:\Users\maako\OneDrive\Documents\DiscordJS\Bumps\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:223
>
> throw new Error(`\`${key}` is an invalid option.`);
>
> Error: `channelID_1032246238126542950` is an invalid option.

Comment: What are the errors and how is your application behaving now? Note that sending messages over multiple channels at once is considered spam and Discord will most likely put a rate limit on it

Comment: **Error**
```C:\Users\maako\OneDrive\Documents\DiscordJS\Bumps\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:223
    throw new Error(`\`${key}\` is an invalid option.`);
          ^

Error: `channelID_1032246238126542950` is an invalid option.```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood what `mongoose.get()` does. What this does is it simply fetches you the options on how to parse data and other things, passed into `mongoose.set()`. So, for example, if at the time of running your bot, you used `mongoose.set("debug", true)` which is one of the options you can pass to `mongoose` (full list of options [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-set)), then you can get the value of `debug` later anywhere else by using `mongoose.get("debug")`. To store data, you would have to create a `Schema`, create a `Model` with it, and then use the `Model` to query data. A simple example:

`Model.js`

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.models["modelName"] || mongoose.model(schema, "modelName", "modelName")
```

`index.js`

```js
const model = require("../filepath/to/model.js")
async function getData() {
    await model.findOne({ name: "your name" })
}
```

(Note: What the `.get()` reminds me of is QuickDB. Since `mongoose` takes some time and effort to set up, it may be easier for you to use QuickDB. You can look up how to store data and stuff in it [here](https://quickdb.js.org/))